# Dism.exe /ResetBase error on Windows server 2016

Tags: windows, mount, windows-server-2016, dism, adk

I'm executing the command

```
DISM /Image:E:\WIM\Mount /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase
```

on an offline mounted WIM Image.

I'm facing this error:

```
Error: 0x800f0806

The operation could not be completed due to pending operations.
```

I've tried

1. sfc /scannow
2. deleted C:\Windows\WinSxS\pending.xml
3. Started another DISM.exe session
4. Cleared Registry keys
5. Mounted to different location (Mount & Re-Mount)

ADK version: 10.1.19041.1

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the ReseBase command on Mounted WIM image would cause error if online operations are pending.

Add this command before adding online packages/updates to the Mounted WIM image.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the name of this dism.exe switch that it will revert pending operation:

```
dism /online /Cleanup-Image /RevertPendingActions
```

To run the above command, open an elevated command prompt.